# Django/Bootstrapping 404 error

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm relatively new to Django and can't work out where I am going wrong.
I am trying to bootstrap my base.html file which looks like the following

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load staticfiles %}
<html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="author" content="Bev">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
        <title class="h1">Bev's Site</title>
    </head>

    <body class="container-fluid">
    {% block content %}

    {% endblock content %}
    <footer class="modal-footer">
    <a class = "url" href="{% url 'add' %}">Post New Item</a>
    <a class="url" href="{% url 'store' %}">Back To The Store</a>
    </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I run this I get the following error message.

```
"GET /static/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1706
```

Any hints or tips to solving this would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that the problem is with your static files.

Ensure the following:
If your static folder (which should contain a directory `css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css`) is in the root of the project, ensure the following code exist in your settings file:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

If your static folder is in a different location like within a Django App, ensure the `"static"` part of the `STATICFILES_DIRS` is something like `"app/static"` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the settings.py to configure static files? First, check django.contrib.staticfiles is included in your INSTALLED_APPS.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'blog',
    'django_countries',
    'djangobower',
]
```

Next check you did define STATIC_URL like this.

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

And check you did stroe your bootstrap.min.css file in a folder called static in your app as below.

```
your_appname/static/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css
```

You can use following code to check where django is looking for your static files.

```
python manage.py findstatic --verbosity 2 css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css
```

I did execute in two ways. Example 1) is the case which my assets/css/styles.css located in wrong directory. And Example 2) is the case that files stroed in appropriate location. If your situation is like Example 1), check the bootstrap files location once again.

Example 1)

```
(envalpha)root@localhost:~/alphago# python manage.py findstatic --verbosity 2 assets/css/styles.css
No matching file found for 'assets/css/styles.css'.
Looking in the following locations:
  /root/anaconda/envs/envalpha/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static
  /root/alphago/blog/static
  /root/anaconda/envs/envalpha/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django_countries/static
```

Example 2)

```
(envalpha)root@localhost:~/alphago# python manage.py findstatic --verbosity 2 assets/css/styles.css    
Found 'assets/css/styles.css' here:
  /root/alphago/blog/static/assets/css/styles.css
Looking in the following locations:
  /root/anaconda/envs/envalpha/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static
  /root/alphago/blog/static
  /root/anaconda/envs/envalpha/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django_countries/static
```